# ¿capturar variables por post y usarlas en consulta sql?

Tags: php, html, sql

Tengo dos `form` que me mandan por `POST` dos ids diferentes, y en otro php los capturo y los guardo en variables (`$v1`, `$v2`) las pongo en un array para saber cual de las dos fue la que llegó con información y la imprimo. Lo que quiero saber es cómo poder usarlas en una consulta para que me traiga los registros pertenecientes a esos id.

```
<?php
// (el que recibe el post y en la que quiero usar los id que envio)
error_reporting(1);
session_start();
require '../login/funcs/conexion.php';
include '../login/funcs/funcs.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}
$idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = '$idUsuario'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `tienda` WHERE id = '$'";
$result1 = $mysqli->query($sql1);
$row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc();

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if ($_POST['vienedelformc'] == 'si') {
        if ($_POST['variablec'] != '') {
            
        } else { 
            
        }
    }
} else {
    
}
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if ($_POST['vienedelformg'] == 'si') {
        if ($_POST['variableg'] != '') {
        } else { 
            
        }
    }
} else { 
    
}
$v1 = $_POST['variablec'];
$v2 = $_POST['variableg'];

$array= array("$v1$v2");
if (empty($array)) {
    echo 'El array está vacío';
} else {
    var_dump($array);
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema o error?

Comment: Puede ser que lo que buscas es hacer un `IN` ejemplo, para optener las filas con id 1 y 5: `SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuarios.id IN(1, 5)` - Si puedes clarifica un poco mas tu pregunta he indica que te pasa exactamente, que es lo que no consigues o cual es el error.

Comment: gracias por responder
como les decia lo que quiero es poder usar los id que mando desde el otro php por medio de post 
los ando guardando en las variables v1 y v2 pero no se como usarlas en la consulta 

lo he intentado asi 

$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `tienda` WHERE id = '$v1' OR id='$v2'"

pero tampoco

Answer (score 0):

hola a todos el error lo resolvi asi

```
<?php
error_reporting(1);
session_start();
require '../login/funcs/conexion.php';
include '../login/funcs/funcs.php';
if(!isset($_SESSION["id_usuario"])){ //Si no ha iniciado sesión redirecciona a index.php
    header("Location: ../index.php");
}
$idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE id = '$idUsuario'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$row = $result->fetch_assoc();


//forma corta
    $v1 = isset($_POST['variablec']) ? $_POST['variablec'] : null;
    //la forma larga es:
    $valores = [];
    $v2 = null;
    $v1  = null;
    if(isset($_POST['variableg'])){
        $v2 = $_POST['variableg'];
        array_push($valores,$v2);
    }
    if(isset($_POST['variablec'])){
        $v1 = $_POST['variablec'];
        array_push($valores,$v1);
    }
    $valores = implode(",",$valores);
    $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `tienda` WHERE id in($valores)";
    $result1 = $mysqli->query($sql1);
    $row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc();

?>

    introducir el código aquí
```